# Python - BS4 - Extracting multiple values from a class

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

when parsing a web-page with bs4, i'm trying to extract multiple values and store them in a dictionary for later use.

Model

```
            <div class="model-dropdown-block">
                <select name="modelpid">
                    <option value="empty">Select Model</option>

                    <option value="MODEL1_530"
                            data-maxavailable="0.0"
                            data-maxorderqty="10"
                           data-status="NOT_AVAILABLE">                                
                           Jet Fighter       </option>


                        <option value="MODEL2_540"
                            data-maxavailable="0.0"
                            data-maxorderqty="10"
                            data-status="NOT_AVAILABLE">                                
                            Jet Fighter2     </option>
```

given the above parsed content, i would like to extract:

1. the associated text (Jet Fighter)
2. option value (MODEL1_530)
3. data-status (NOT-AVAILABLE)

and insert them into a dictionary key/value pair, with multiple values, so that the result is  **Jet Fighter:Model1530, Not available**

I need the data for later use, but i am open to suggestion on a more efficient way to store it for later retrieval.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
allmodels = soup.findAll('div', {'class':'model-dropdown-block'})

for model in allmodels: 
    for modelvar in model.findAll('option'): 
        print(sizevar['value'])
```

so as expected, this does capture all of the option values. I need to be able to omit the first option, which is always empty and then create the dictionary as described.

I am unsure as to how i would need to edit my for loop, to pickup the additional info. I tried:

```
for model in allmodels: 
    for modelvar in model.findAll('option'): 
        print(sizevar['value'],[data-status])
```

but this does not produce any results, i understand that to be finding all option or data-status attributes but clearly my understanding is incorrect!

first post on here, so thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will do the trick as only had that little snippet of html to work with. But managed to get the output you were looking for.

```
import bs4


html = '''<div class="model-dropdown-block">
                <select name="modelpid">
                    <option value="empty">Select Model</option>

                    <option value="MODEL1_530"
                            data-maxavailable="0.0"
                            data-maxorderqty="10"
                           data-status="NOT_AVAILABLE">                                
                           Jet Fighter       </option>


                        <option value="MODEL2_540"
                            data-maxavailable="0.0"
                            data-maxorderqty="10"
                            data-status="NOT_AVAILABLE">                                
                            Jet Fighter2     </option>'''




soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')


allmodels = soup.findAll('div', {'class':'model-dropdown-block'})[0]
models = allmodels.find_all('option')


model_dict = {}
for model in models: 

    model_key = model.text.strip()
    option_value = model.get('value')
    data_status = model.get('data-status')

    model_dict[model_key] = [option_value, data_status]
```

**Output:**

```
print (model_dict)
{'Select Model': ['empty', None], 'Jet Fighter': ['MODEL1_530', 'NOT_AVAILABLE'], 'Jet Fighter2': ['MODEL2_540', 'NOT_AVAILABLE']}
```

Comment: Worked a treat...thank you very much sir!

So i understand what its going:

1. we loop on models under the option class(?)
2. .text i  assume is needed to grab the text within the class and we strip the whitespace?
3. option value i understand, this is what is was able to achieve but ty for helping with the dictionary
4. using my code, when I change the attribute to look for from VALUE to DATA-STATUS, i constantly got key errors, not sure why i couldnt get it on its own...
5. we then use the empty dict, model text being the key and i now understand how to add multiple values...

Comment: Yup you got it! Just keep practicing. I only started about 2 months ago with beautifulsoup. I still have to look up syntax, but I keep picking up the concept more and more, the more practice I do.